# Need some ideas to add intelligent wait in XCUI Tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

Adding intelligent wait before tapping on every button

I have added a function which is being called every time it taps on element

```
//    if button.exists {
//      button.tap()
//    } else if !button.exists {
//      sleep(10)
//      button.tap()
//
//    } else {
//      print("***************** Unable to find " + button.title + " *****************")
//    }
```

---

I call like this Pagename.tapBtn(element)
I need some common function without sleep... I do not know how can i use predicate to tackle this.

Comment: You shall not access XCUIElement's properties if the element itself does not exist. This will abort the test execution.

Answer (score 1):

You shall probably use something like

```
extension XCUIElement {
     func waitAndTap() {
        _ = waitForExistence(timeout: 30)
        tap()
     }
}
```

This extension function will tap element as soon as it exists. If it is not it will fail.

Notice I ditched error message because `tap()` will automatically produce it.

Comment: A better solution can be to use the `waitForExistence()` function inside an assert : `XCTAssert(self.waitForExistence(timeout: 30), "Element not found")` and then use the `tap()` function.

Comment: "Element not found" is not a great error message. `tap()` will produce much more detailed one.

Comment: so will waitForExistence wait for 30 seconds everytime or its max time out?

Comment: It will wait for no longer than 30 seconds. It will wait just needed amount of time.